# Сгрупировка времени в интервалы по условию SQL

Tags: sql, время

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста с запросом, есть вот такие данные: нужно разбить эти данные на интервалы, по колонке status, чтобы примерно выглядело так:
client, date_start, date_end, status

1, 01.06.2019 0:00:00, 01.06.2019 0:02:00, 2

1, 01.06.2019 0:02:00, 01.06.2019 0:04:00, 1

1, 01.06.2019 0:04:00, 01.06.2019 0:05:00, 2

.......

Comment: А для последней записи что должно получиться?

Comment: тут везде интервал в 1 минуту, поэтому будет 
1, 01.06.2019 0:11:00, 01.06.2019 0:12:00, 2